# C# Reading file in a directory

Tags: c#

I have an app that reads a CSV file called “words.csv”. My new requirement is that 1) it needs to ensure that there is only one CSV file in the directory before reading. 2) It should read any file with ".CSV" extension not just “words.csv” (after condition 1 is satisfied). Hope this makes sense?
Can anyone assist?

```
public class VM
{
    public VM()
    {
        Words = LoadWords(fileList[0]);
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Words { get; private set; }

    string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(@"Z:\My Documents\", "*.csv");


    private static IEnumerable<string> LoadWords(String fileList)
    {

        List<String> words = new List<String>();

        if (fileList.Length == 1)
        {

            try
            {
                foreach (String line in File.ReadAllLines(fileList))
                {
                    string[] rows = line.Split(',');

                    words.AddRange(rows);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }

            return words;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this code to get a list of all the csv files in a folder:

```
string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles( @"Z:\My Documents\", "*.csv");
```

So to satisfy your conditions, this should do the trick:

```
string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles( @"Z:\My Documents\", "*.csv");
if( fileList.Length == 1 )
{
  //perform your logic here
}
```

Comment: You can basically use the same code. Replace my comment above with your code, and instead of `filePath` you will have to use `fileList[0]` to get the path of the file.

Comment: Thanks, im getting alot of errors to do with conversion of string to string[], are you seeing the same thing?

Comment: On which line to you get that error? Please post that line from your code here.

Comment: I have edited my code above to show you what I have can you assist? Thanks

Comment: The problem is here: private static IEnumerable<string> LoadWords(String fileList)

Comment: Four problems: Send the entire filelist into LoadWords, not only LoadWords[0]. Have LoadWords take string[] as parameter instead of string. In the the foreach, put  File.ReadAllLines(fileList[0]) instead. LoadWords do not return anything if the file is not found. Return words anyway since it will just be empty if the file is not found anyway.

Comment: This is still not working for me could you post the solution please. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Its failing with the message "not all code paths return a value"

Comment: That's what I said in the last point in my comment. You have to move `return words;` outside the if block of LoadWords. So move it two lines down, and you should be good to go :)

Answer (score 1):

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"Z:\My Documents");

// Get a reference to each file in that directory. 
FileInfo[] fiArr = di.GetFiles();

if(fiArr.Length ==1)
{
FileInfo fri = fiArr[0];
    //use fri.Extension to check for csv
    //process as required
}
```

[MSDN:DirectoryInfo.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cyf24ss.aspx)

[MSDN: FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
FileInfo file = new DirectoryInfo(@"Z:\My Documents")
                            .EnumerateFiles("*.csv")
                            .SingleOrDefault();

if (file != null)
{
   //do your logic
}
```

Linq's SingleOrDefault operator will make sure there's exactly onle file with the given pattern otherwise it will return null